# HA options for a VLDB

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, high-availability, disaster-recovery, vldb

We have 2 VLDB's - 6TB (primary db, not much OLTP traffic) and 4TB (archive db). Data will be moved/archived (delete from primary and insert to archive) daily from 5 large tables. Currently this server is on 2016 Standard Edition and holds 2 VLDB's and 1 small db. We are planning for an HADR strategy, considering standard edition i can only think of log shipping (sometimes log backup ranges 2-5gb) or FCI. If, we upgrades to Enterprise edition we can use AlwaysOn AG's. My question is what is the best strategy for these 2 VLDB's. And considering more features are getting added in future for primary DB, so size will grow and becomes more high OLTP system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, your best bet would be to upgrade to **Enterprise Edition** and implement **AlwaysOn Availability Groups**. Depending on how much reporting you do and how high the availability needs to be, you might even want to set it up with two secondary replicas (for a total of three nodes).

Alternatively if you do stick with **Standard Edition**, aside from **Log Shipping** and regular **FCI**, you can also use [**Replication**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-ver15) to synchronize your data across multiple servers in **near real-time**, especially since your **OLTP** is not that much, actually. [**SSIS**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services?view=sql-server-ver15) is another way you can synchronize data between servers too, though it's a bit more *clunky* and might not be as *real-time* as **Replication**.

Basic Availability Groups are also an option in Standard Edition. It's not really a "group" since each AG can only contain 1 DB, and only span 2 nodes, among some other limitations--but essentially provide the same functionality previously supported via mirroring.

Comment: Basic Availability Groups are also an option in Standard Edition. It's not really a "group" since each AG can only contain 1 DB, and only span 2 nodes, among some other limitations--but essentially provide the same functionality previously supported via mirroring